# How powerful is the name of Shri Ram?

Tags: rama, ramanand, ramnandacharya

How great is the name of Shri Ram? How can you prove your answer?

Comment: What do you mean by proof of answer? Scriptures is sufficient I presume?

Answer (score 3):

सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।

अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।

As said by Śrī Vedā Vyās in Padmā Purān;

न संहिता सा नहि यत्र रामो न सोऽस्ति वेदो नाहि यत्र रामः।

स नेतिहासो नहि यत्र रामः न तत् पुराणं नहि यत्र रामः॥

Lord Shri Ved Vyas says that Samhitā is not Samhitā, that Vedā is not Vedā, that Purān is not Purān, that Itīhāas is not Itīhāas where Śrī Rām and his name is not there. (Same shloka also available in Nārad Panchrātra)

Around same meaning Shlokā is also found in Brihād Kaūshal Khänd, Vëd Vyās uvāch,

न तत्पुराणो नहि यत्र रामो यस्यां न रामो नहि संहिता सा स नेतिहासो नहि यत्र रामो काव्यं न तत्स्यान्नहि यत्र रामः॥

शास्त्र न तत्स्थानहि यत्र रामस्तीर्थं न तद्यत्र न रामचन्द्रः यागः स धागो न हि यत्र रामो योगः स रोगो नहि यत्ररामः॥

न सा सभा यत्र न रामचन्द्रः कालोऽप्यकालः कलिरेव सोऽस्ति ।

संकीर्त्यते यत्र न रामदेवो विद्याऽप्यविद्या रहिताह्यनेन।।

स्थानं मयस्थानमरामकीतिर्रामेति नाम्ना मुखशून्यमस्य।

सर्पालयं प्रेतगृहं गृहं तद्यत्रार्चते नैव महेशपूज्यः ॥

उक्तेन किं स्यात्बहुनाति विश्वं सर्वं मृषा स्याद्यदिरामशून्यम्।

एतच्चकृष्णः पुनराह नोऽसौ स्पृष्ट्वोपवीतं जपमालिकाञ्च।।

Glory of Śrī Rām naam has been sung in all samhitas, this servent is quoting few of them. Please read it and chant the sweetest name of the entire universe SītāRām. Here we go;

1. Agastyā Samhitā (अगस्त्य संहिता)

Shri Shīv sentence towards Shri Rām

अहं भवन्नामजपन्कृतार्थो वसामि काश्यामनिशं भवान्या।

मरिष्यमाणस्य विमुक्तयेऽपि दिशामि मन्त्रं तव रामनाम।।

O Shri Rām ji! Chanting your auspicious Shri Rām naam with Bhavani, I live in Kashi with gratitude. Preachs your Shri Ram naam to the dying creatures in their 'right ear' for their salvation. (कासीं मरत जंतु अवलोकी। जासु नाम बल करउँ बिसोकी।।~manas)

रकारो रामचन्द्रस्स्यात्साच्चेदानन्दविग्रहः।

अकारो जानकीप्रोक्ता मकारो लक्ष्मणः स्वराट्।।

The meaning of 'R' in Shri Ram naam is Sachchidanand Vigraha Swaroop Shri Ramji, "A" means Shri Janakiji and "M" means self-illuminated Shri Lakshmanji.

रकारेण बाहिर्याति मकरेण विशेत्पुनः।

रामरामेति सच्छन्दो जीवो जपति सर्वदा।

The best process of Ajpajap is to pronounce "Ra" while exhaling and "M" while inhaling . In this way the soul chants this holy word Rām Rām forever.

दैन्यं दिनं तु दुरितं पक्षमासर्तुवर्षजम् ।

सर्वं दहति निःशेषं तूलाचलमिवानलः ॥

All the sins committed in a year, season, month, fortnight and a day, by chanting the name of Shri Rām once, the Sāklyën is reduced to ashes in the same way as a mountain of cotton is reduced to ashes on the touch of fire.

नामसंकीर्तनश्चैव गुणानामपि कीर्त्तनम्।

भक्त्या श्रीरामचन्द्रस्य वचसा शुद्धिरिष्यते ।।

Devotionally chanting the name of Lord Shri Sitaram ji with your voice and chanting and singing the virtues of Lord is the purification of speech and life.

2. Vishwāmitra Samhitā (विश्वामित्र संहिता)

Vishwamitra sentence towards Vaïshy;

विश्रुतानि बहून्येव तीर्थानि विविधानि च।

कोट्यंशान्नापि तुल्यानि नाम संकीर्त्तनस्य वै ॥

Many pilgrimages are famous in Vedas and Puranas in many ways, but all those pilgrimages definitely cannot even match the crores of parts of Shri Rām naam sankirtan.

धन्याः पुण्याः प्रपन्नास्ते भाग्ययुक्ता कलौयुगे ।

संविहायाथ योगादीन् रामनामैक नैष्ठिकः ॥

Those people are very fortunate, blessed, pious and godly, who keep complete devotion in chanting the name of Shri Ram, leaving all other means of yoga.

रकारो रामरूपस्तु मकारस्तस्य सेवकः ।

आचार्यस्तु ह्याकारः स्यात्तयो: संयोजनाय च ॥

The meaning of 'R' in the name of Shri Ram is Lord Rama, and the meaning of "M" is only the servant of Shri Ramji. The meaning of "A" is the Acharya who unites the soul with God.

राम रामेति यो नित्यं मधुरं जपति क्षणम् ।

सर्वसिद्धिमाप्नोति सत्यं नैवात्र संशयः ।।

One who chants Shri Ram Ram Ram in a melodious voice even for a moment. He gets all the achievements.

ब्रह्मघ्नश्च सुरारापश्च स्तया च गुरुतल्पगः ।

शरणागतघाती च मित्रविश्रम्भकारकः ।।

लब्धं परं पदं तेन जन्म कोटिभिरर्जितम् ।

कीर्त्तितं येन महत्ता श्रीरामेत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

The person who kills a brahmin, a drunkard, a thief, seeing Guru's wife with lust, a refugee killer and betrayer of a friend, easily attains that supreme state, which is going to be obtained from the good deeds earned in crores of births, who chanted these two letters "Shri Ram".

ज्ञातमध्यात्मशास्त्रं च प्राप्तं तेनामृतं महत्।

कीर्त्तितं येन वचसा श्रीरामेत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

The one who utters these two letters ‘Ra’ ‘m’ once in his speech, he has studied the entire spiritual science (Vedanta) and has attained the great nectar of ultimate salvation.

सर्वमन्त्रमयं नाम यन्त्रास्पदमनुत्तमम्।

स्वाभाविकीं परां सिद्धिं दुर्लभां तज्ज्माल्लभेत् ॥

The name of Shri Rām is the all-mantra and the best yantra swaroop, by chanting which very rare Para Siddha is attained naturally.

वृथा नाना प्रयोगेषु मन्त्रतन्त्रेषु मानवाः।

यत्नं कुर्वन्त्यहो मूढास्त्यक्त्वा श्रीनाम सुन्दरम्।।

It is a matter of great surprise that except the name of Paramsundar Shri Rām, foolish people work in vain in many experiments, mantras and tantras.

यस्य संस्मरणादेव सर्वार्थाश्चक्षुगोचराः ।

भवन्त्येवानायासेन तच्छ्रीराममहं भजे ॥

I worship that Lord Shri Ram, by whose proper remembrance one can easily see all things directly.

3. Saur Samhitā (सौर संहितायाम्)

श्रीरामनाममनिशं परिकीर्त्तनीयं वर्तेत मोद सु निधानमशेष सारम् ।

जन्मार्जितानि विविधान्यपहाय दुःखान्यत्यन्त धर्म निचयं परधाममेति ॥

Kirtan of Shri Ram's name, the essence of joy, should be done continuously, by doing this, the soul gets free from the sorrows arising from various sins committed in many births and goes to the supreme abode after attaining the most virtuous group.

स सागरां महीं दत्त्वा शुद्धकाञ्चन पूर्णिताम्।

यत्फलं लभते लोके नामोच्चारस्ततोऽधिकम् ।।

By donating the pure golden earth along with all the oceans to a good deity, the fruit that is obtained in the world, is many times more in chanting the name of Shri Rām.

वाच्यश्श्रीरामचन्द्रस्तु वाचको नाम संस्मृतम् ।

वाच्यवाचक सम्बन्धो नित्यमेव न संशयः ॥

Lord Shri Ram is the Vächyā and the Vāchak is the name of Shri Ram. There is no doubt about the eternal relationship between the Vāchak and Vächyā.

3. Jābäli Samhitā (जाबाली संहिता)

रामनाम परं जाप्यं ज्ञेयं ध्येयं निरन्तरम् ।

कीर्त्तनीयं च बहुधा मुमुक्षुभिरहर्निशम् ।।

Shri Ram Naam is worthy of constant chanting, knowledge, meditation and kirtan in many ways for the mumukshupurusha.

श्रीरामनाम सामर्थ्यादखिलेष्टं करे स्थितम्।

भवन्ति कृत पुण्यानां यथाकल्पतरोर्धनम्॥

For those who chant the name of Shri Ram, all the desired things are located in their palm by the power of Shri Ram Naam, just as for the pious souls, all the wealth is present from the Kalpavriksha.

नाम्नि यस्य रतिर्नास्ति स वै चाण्डालतोऽधिकः ।

सम्भाषणं न कर्तव्यं तत्समं नामतत्परैः ।।

The one who does not have love in the name of Shri Ram, he is definitely a Chandal. Devotees who are fond of Shri Ram Naam should not talk to them.

रामनाम प्रभा दिव्या यस्योरसि प्रकाशते ।

तस्यास्ति सुलभं सर्वं सौख्यं सर्वेशजं परम् ॥

For that Mahatma in whose heart the divine effulgence of Sri Rama's name shines, all the transcendental pleasures related to the Lord become easily accessible.

साधनेन बिना सिद्धिर्दृष्टं नाम्नैव संस्फुटम्।

अन्यत्र साधनैः दुखै दुर्लभं तन्महत् सुखम् ||

Without means and labor, all perfection and happiness are attained by Sri Ram naam. Without Sri Ram naam, that great happiness cannot be attained by many other painful means.

4. Soot Samhitā (सूत संहितायाम्)

यः श्रीरामपदं नरः प्रतिपदं संकीर्तयन्तत्क्षणान्मुक्तो दुष्कृतराशितो बुधजनैः पूज्यो विवस्व भः ।

त्यक्त्वा संसृति मृत्यु दु:ख पटलं संशुद्धचित्तः पुमान् श्रीरामास्पदमुन्नतं पर पदं प्राप्नोत्ययासं विना ॥

The person who chants Shri Ram's name at every step, from that very moment becomes free from sins, becomes worshiped by all the gods, becomes as bright as the sun. By renouncing the world cycle, death and sorrow group, being the most pure mind, without any effort, attains the most elevated supreme position, Shri Ram Dham.

रिपवस्तस्य नश्यन्ति न बाधन्ते ग्रहाश्च तम् ।

राक्षसाश्च न खादन्ति नरं रामेती ने वादिनम् ॥

Whoever chants the name of Śrī Ram, all his enemies are destroyed, no planet can afflicts him, and demons, ghosts and demons cannot devour him.

(This shloka was said was Śrīmad Tulsidas Ji Maharaj in his hymns as;

जब जानकी नाथ सहाय करे तब कौन विगार करे नर तेरो।

सूरज मंगल सोम भृगुसत बुध अरु गुरु वरदायक प्रेरो।

राहुकेतु की कौन गम्यता चन्द्र शनिश्चर होत हैं चेरो।।)

अहो धैर्यमहोधैर्यमहोधैर्यमिदं नृणाम्।

रामनाम्न स्थिते लोके न भजन्ति बहिर्मुखः ॥

It is surprising that the teaching is so wonderfully serious that even though Sri Ramanam is signed in this world, people with extroverted attitudes are not chanting bhajans.

रामनामामृतं पीत्वा भवेत्रित्वं निरामयम् ।

सिद्धान्तं सारमित्येकं साधूनां भावितात्मनाम् ||

Saints with pure conscience have only one principle that by drinking the nectar in the form of Shriram's name, you should be free from all diseases for ever and ever.

श्रीरामं रामभद्रं च सीतारामं सुखाकरम्।

इतीरयन्ति ये नित्यं ते वै धन्यतमा नराः||

Shri Rām, Rāmbhadrā and SītāRām Those who happily chant the names of the Lord in this way are certainly blessed.

5. Brahmā Samhitā (ब्रह्म संहिता)

Sri Shiva Sentence

रामेति वर्णद्वयमादरेण सदा स्मरन्मुक्तिमुपैति जन्तुः।

कलौ युगे कल्मषमानसानामन्यत्र धर्मे खलुनाधिकारः ॥

The soul who always remembers these two letters "Shri Ram" with respect, attains liberation. In this fierce Kaliyuga, souls with a dirty heart definitely have no right in any other religion.

यन्नामकीर्त्तन फलं विविधं निशम्य न श्रद्दधाति मनुते यदुतार्थवादम्।

यो मानुषस्तमिह दुःखचये क्षिपामि संसार घोर विविधार्त्तिनिपीडितान्नम् ॥

The person who does not believe in the name of Shri Ram after listening to the different types of fruits of the chanting of the name of Shri Ram, but considers the glory to be just an economicism, I throw that person in the sea of ​​sorrows, who is suffering from many severe sorrows of the world.

कलिप्रभावतो नष्टाः सद्ग्रन्थानां कथाः शुभाः ।

पाखण्डैर्निर्मितं नानामतं श्रीनाम वर्जितम् ॥

Due to the effect of Kali Yuga, the auspicious stories of the scriptures have been destroyed. Hypocrites have created many sects devoid of the name of Shri Ram. (This also have been mentioned in Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas Uttarkānd)

अतस्सर्वं परित्यज्य नामसंस्मरणे रताः ।

त एव कृतकृत्याश्च सर्व वेदार्थ कोविदाः ॥

That is why, apart from all other means, those who are engaged in the remembrance of Sri Rama Naam are actually the satisfied and the scholars of all Vedic meaning.

श्रीरामेति वदन् जीवो याति ब्रह्म सनातनम् ।

सर्वाचारविहीनोऽपि ताप क्लेशादि संयुतः ॥

Even those beings who are devoid of all virtues and are endowed with sorrow and trouble attain the eternal Brahman by chanting the name of Sri Rām.

यस्य भासा सर्वमिदं विभातीति श्रुतेः ।

प्रकाशो रामचन्द्रस्य परब्रह्म प्रकाशिनः ॥

भास्करस्य यथा धर्मश्चन्द्रस्य चन्द्रिकोज्वला ।

The light of Śrī Rāmachandrā is the light of the Supreme Brahman, just as the religion of the sun is to illuminate the moon with its light. Similarly, it is described in the scriptures that everything is illuminated by the same Śrī Rāmachandrā. (Same quoted in mānas as , जगत प्रकाश्य प्रकाश कर रामू)

पूर्णोपूर्णावतारश्च श्यामोरामोरघूत्तमः ।

अंशानृसिंहकृष्णाद्याः राघवोभगवान्स्वयम् ॥

Sri Rama of dark complexion is Raghushrestha and perfect. Sri Ram is God Himself, from whose fragment Narasimha, Krishna and others all appears.

6. Bodhāyan Samhita (बोधायन संहितायाम्)

इष्टापूर्त्तानि कर्माणि सुबहूनि कृतान्यपि ।

भव हेतूनि तान्येव रामनाम्ना सुमुक्तयः ।।

All the auspicious deeds that are done in spite of proper rituals of Yajna etc. virtuous deeds are the reason for the whole world and not in salvation. Salvation can be achieved only by the name of Shri Ram, not by other means.

श्रीमद्रामेतिनाम्नस्तु सदा सर्वत्र कीर्त्तनम् ।

नाशौचं कीर्त्तने तस्य स पवित्रकरो यतः ॥

Kirtan of Sri Ram Naam should always be done, there should be no thought of purity or impurity in the Sankirtan of Sri Ram Naam, because Sri Ram Naam in itself is holy and makes the impure also pure.

रामनामानि लोकेस्मिन् सर्वदा यस्तु कीर्त्तयेत् ।

तस्यापराधकोटिस्तु क्षमाम्येव न संशयः ॥

Sri Rām ji says that there is no doubt that I forgive millions of sins of one who always chants my name in this world.

न तादृशं महाभाग पापं लोकेषु विश्रुतम् ।

यादृशं विप्र शार्दूल रामनाम्ना विदह्यते ॥

O most fortunate one! O best of Brahmins, I do not see any strong and famous sin in this world that cannot be consumed by the utterance of Sri Rama Naam.

श्रीरामनाम सामर्थ्यमतुलं विद्यते द्विज।

न हि पापात्मकस्तावत्पापं कर्तुं क्षमः क्षितौ ।।

O best Brahmin! The power of the name of Shri Ram is infinite; no sinner on earth can commit as much sin as can be destroyed by remembering the name of Shri Ram.

7. Tāpniye Samhitā (तापनीय संहितायाम्)

सर्वेषामेव दोषाणां प्रायश्चित्तं परं स्मृतम् ।

अपमृत्यु प्रशमनं मूलाविद्या विनाशनम् ॥

The greatest atonement for all evils is said to be Sri Ramanam, which is the reliever of immortality, the destroyer of eternal ignorance.

नाम संकीर्त्तनं विद्धि अतो नान्यद्वदाम्यहम्।

सर्वस्वं रामचन्द्रस्य तन्नामानन्त वैभवम्॥

So I do not say anything else, just believe the truth that the chanting of Sri Ram Naam is also the everything of Lord Sri Ram, therefore the glory of Sri Ram Naam is infinite.

स्वप्नेऽपि यो वदेन्नित्यं रामनाम परात्परम्।

सोऽपि पातकराशीनां दाहको भवति ध्रुवम्।।

Even those who daily chant the Supreme Sri Ram Naam even in their dreams, Sri Ram Naam Maharaj surely burns away their sins.

पापद्रुमकुठारोऽयं पापेन्धनदावानलम् ।

पापराशितमस्तोमं रविः साक्षात्प्रभानिधिः॥

Shriram's name is like an axe for a sinful tree, like a bonfire to burn sinful wealth, and like a sunbeam to destroy the darkness of sin.

रामनाम परंधाम पवित्रं पावनास्पदम् ।

अतः परं न सन्म स्तारकं विद्यते क्वचित् ॥

Sri Ram Naam is the only supreme place of divine effulgence, holy, sanctifying, there is no other good Tarak mantra than this.

8. Hiranyagarbha Samhita (हिरण्यगर्भ संहिता)

(Shri Agastya's sentence towards Sutikshna)

अभिरामेति यन्नाम कीर्त्तितं विवशाच्च यैः ।

तेऽपि ध्वस्ताखिलाघौघा यान्ति रामास्पदं परम् ॥

Those who uttered the word AbhiRam instead saying Sri Ram and also those who uttered Sri Rām Naam under compulsion (submission) all their sins are destroyed and they attain the divine abode of Lord Sri Rām.

श्रीरामेति वदन्ब्रह्मभावमाप्नोत्यसंशयम्।

तत्त्वविद्यार्थिनो नित्यं रमन्ते चित्सुखात्मनि।।

As soon as the name of Shri Ram is recited, the soul attains Brahma Bhava without any doubt. Sadhaks who wish for Tatva vidya, always rejoice in the name of Sachidānand Shri Rām.

इति रामपदेनासौ परं ब्रह्माभिधीयते ।

सर्वसिद्धान्तमित्याहुः सर्वे वै ब्रह्मवादिन: ।।

The name of Shri Rām is Par-Brahmā, all Brahmaists call this as Sarvasiddhanta.

श्रीरामेति परं मन्त्रं तदेव परमं पदम्।

तदेव तारकं विद्धि जन्म मृत्यु भयापहम्।।

Know Sri Rama Naam as the supreme mantra, the Param Pad, the Tarak mantra and the destroyer of fear in the form of birth and death.

अल्पेन नाम्ना कथमस्य पापक्षयो भवेदत्र न शङ्कनीयम्।

तृणादि राशिं दहतेऽल्पवह्निस्तथा महामोहमदादि नाम ॥

How will a little Ram Naam destroy the great sins of this sinner? There should be no such doubt here because just as a little fire destroys a group of grass, so the remembrance of Sri Rama Naam destroys great envy.

9. Pulah Samhitā (पुलह संहिता)

बीजे यथा स्थितो वृक्षः शाखा पल्लव संयुतः।

तथैव सर्ववेदाश्च रकारेषु व्यवस्थिताः॥

Just as a tree with branches and leaves sits in the seed, so the entire Vedas are arranged in "R" meaning that by chanting and remembering the name of Sri Rama, the meanings of the entire Vedic scriptures become illuminated in the heart.

यथा करण्डे रत्नानि गुप्तान्यज्ञैर्न दृश्यन्ते ।

तथैव सर्व मन्त्राश्च रकारेषु व्यवस्थिताः ॥

Just as the ignorant cannot see the jewels kept inside the box, in the same way all mantra tantra is arranged in "R".

रकारोच्चारणेनैव बहिर्निर्याति पातकम् ।

पुनः प्रवेशकाले च मकारस्तु कपाटवत् ॥

By pronouncing ’’R’' of Shri Ram Naam, all the sins of the body come out, so that they cannot enter again, "M" closes the mouth like a valve.

सावित्री ब्रह्मणा सार्द्धं लक्ष्मीर्नारायणेन च ।

शम्भुना रामरामेति पार्वती जपति स्फुटम् ॥

Savitriji with Brahmaji, Lord Narayan with Lakshmiji and Parvatiji with Shankarji chant Ram Ram in clear words.

रामरामेति रामेति स्वपन् जायँस्तथा निशि ।

ये जपन्ति कलौ नित्यं ते वै श्रीरामरूपिणः॥

Those who chant Ram Ram daily while sleeping, waking up and at night, in Kaliyug, they are actually the form of Shri Ram (Ānand Swarōop).

10. Parāshara Samhitā (पराशर संहिता)

Vyas ji's sentence towards Samb;

न साम्ब व्याधिजं दुःखं हेयं नानौषधैरपि ।

रामनामौषधं पीत्वा व्याधेस्त्यागो न संशयः ।।

O Sāmb, the pain caused by leprosy will not go away even with many medicines and by drinking the greatest medicine of the name of Shri Ram, the disease will definitely go away, so take the medicine of name of Shri Ram. (Samb is Lord Śrī Krishnā's son)

कोटिजन्मार्जितं पापमौषधैः शान्तिमेति किम् ।

कीर्त्तनीयं परं नाम भवव्याधेस्तदौषधम् ॥

Will the disease arising from the sin acquired in millions of births be relieved by medicines? No, therefore chant the name of Śrī Rām, the destroyer of the great disease of the world.

सर्व रोगोपशमनं सर्वाधीनां विनाशनम् ।

स्मर त्वं रामरामेति महामोदैकमन्दिरम्।।

Remembrance of Sri Rama Naam is the soothing of all diseases, the destroyer of all adhis (mental pain) and the abode of great joy.

श्रीरामनामविमुखं जीवं शोधयितुं क्षमम् ।

प्रायश्चित्तं न चैवास्ति किश्चत् सत्यं वचो मम ||

There is no atonement for the purification of the living beings who are alienated from the name of Shri Ram, this is my word true.

प्रायश्वित्तेषु सर्वेषु रामनाम जपं परम् ।

यतीनां रामभक्तानां सर्वरीत्या विशिष्यते ॥

Among all the penances, chanting of Sri Rama Naam is the best atonement. For Sannyasis and devotees of Rama, chanting of Śrī Rām Naam in particular is the supreme atonement.

11. Sanatkumara Samhita (सनतकुमार संहिता)

Sri Vyasaji's statement to Yudhisthira

श्रीरामेति परं जाप्यं तारकं ब्रह्मसंज्ञकम्।

ब्रह्महत्यादि पापघ्नमिति वेदविदोविदुः ॥

O Rajan, the learned people who know the Vedas, know and say that the best mantra to be chanted is Sri Rama Naam, the Tarak Brahm and the destroyer of sins like brahma-hatya.

श्रीरामरामेति जना ये जपन्ति च सर्वदा ।

तेषां भुक्तिश्च मुक्तिश्च भविष्यति न संशयः ॥

Those who chant Śrī Rām Rām in this way will surely attain the means of all enjoyment in this world and liberation in the next.

ब्रह्महत्यादि पापानि तत्समानि बहूनि च ।

स्वर्णस्तेयसुरापानगुरुतल्पायुतानि च।।

गोवधाद्युपपापानि अनृतात्सम्भवानि च।

सर्वैः प्रमुच्यते पापैः कल्पायुतशतोद्भवैः ॥

He becomes free from the sins like Brahmahatya and many other sins like, theft of gold, drinking alcohol, thousand times kāam bhavana for teacher's wife, cow slaughter etc. one who pronounces Shri Ram naam.

मानसं वाचिकं पापं कर्मणा समुपार्जितम् ।

श्रीरामस्मरणेनैव तत्क्षणान्नश्यति ध्रुवम् ॥

The sins that have been accumulated by the mind, speech and deeds, all those sins are definitely destroyed at the same moment by remembering the name of Shri Ram.

इदं सत्यमिदं सत्यं सत्यमेतदिहोच्यते।

रामः सत्यं परब्रह्म रामात्किंचिन्न विद्यते ॥

This is truth truth truth that Lord Sri Ram is the truth and Par-Brahmā there is nothing other than Śrī Rām ji.

12. Sushrut Samhita (सुश्रुतसंहिता)

दृष्टो येनैव श्रीरामस्तथा तन्नामकीर्त्तनम् ।

कृतं सर्वं शुभं तेन जितं जन्म सुदुर्लभम्।।

Whoever has realized Lord Sri Rām and whoever has chanted Sri Rām Naam has performed all the Vedic rituals and has conquered this very rare human body.

कारणं प्रणवस्यापि रामनाम जगद्गुरुम्।

तस्माद्वेयं सदा चित्ते यतिभिः शुद्धचेतनैः ॥

The root of Vedas is Pranav (Om) and its ultimate reason is the name of Jagadguru Shri Rām. That's why sannyasins with a pure mind should always meditate on the name of Śrī Ram in their mind.

प्रमादादपि श्रीरामराम उच्चरितं जनैः।

भष्मी भवन्ति पापानि रोगानीव रसायनैः ॥

When people chant Sri Rama Naam even by negligence, sins are burnt away in the same way that diseases are burnt away by chemicals.

तदेव लग्नं सुदिनं तदेव ताराबलं चन्द्रबलं तदेव ।

विद्याबलं दैवबलं तदेव सीतापतेर्नाम यदा स्मरामि ॥

At the time when I chant the name of Shri Sitaram, auspicious lagna, Sudin, Tarabal, Chandrabal, Vidyabal and the destiny etc. all are at good signs.

सर्वाभिलाषं पूर्णार्थं जपेन्नामपरात्परम्।

सर्वं त्यक्त्वा ततो याति ह्यवशं पदमव्ययम्।।

For the fulfillment of all one's desires, one should chant the Supreme Name of Sri Rama, leaving other means behind. This will surely lead him to the indestructible supreme position.

13. Katyayan Samhitā (कात्यायन संहितायाम्)

नाम संकीर्त्तनाज्जातं पुण्यं नोपचयन्ति ये ।

नाना व्याधि समायुक्ताः शतजन्मसु ते नराः।।

Those who do not accumulate the merits arising out of the chanting of Sri Rama's name. Those people get infected with many diseases in thousands of births.

अर्थवादं परे नाम्नि भावयन्तीह यो नरः ।

स पापिष्ठो मनुष्याणां निरये पतति स्फुटम् |

Those who, after listening to the glory of the name of Shri Ram, consider it to be mere arthavad, they are the most sinners among humans and will surely go to hell in the end.

श्रीरामनाममाहात्म्यं याथार्थ्यं श्रुति संमतम् ।

कुतर्कं ये प्रकुर्वन्ति तेऽधमाः पापयोनयः ॥

The greatness of Sri Rām's’ Naam is true and scriptural. Those who argue about that are vile and sinful.

रामरामेति रामेति प्रत्यहं वक्ति यो नरः ।

सम्यक् पूजायुतं पुण्यं तीर्थकोटि फलं लभेत् ॥

One who chants Ram Ram Ram like this daily gets the merit of worshiping the deities thousands of times and the merit of crores of pilgrimages.

यस्तु पुत्रः शुचिर्दक्षः पूर्वे वयसि धार्मिकः ।

रामनाम परं नित्यं तत्पुत्रं कवयो विदुः॥

The son who is pure, clever and religious in the name of Shri Ram in his childhood. Scholars have called him the true.

14. Vaishvanar Samhita (वैश्वानर संहितायाम्)

न देशकालनियमो न शौचाशौचनिर्णयः ।

विद्यते कुत्रचिन्नैव रामनाम्नि परे शुचौ ।।

There is no rule of holy place, death date, defecation etc. for chanting, remembrance, kirtan of Shri Rām naam. There is no expectation from anyone because Shri Rām naam is beyond everyone.

रामेति नित्यं यो भक्त्या ब्रूयाद्रात्रिदिवं नरः।

महापातककोटिभ्यो मुक्तः पूतो भवेत्तु सः ॥

The person who recites the name of Shriram with devotion day and night, he is saved from crores of great sins. Definitely become free and become supremely pure.

रामनामात्मकं मन्त्रं सततं कीर्त्तयन्ति ये ।

सर्वरोगविनिर्मुक्तो मुक्तिमाप्नोति दुर्लभाम्।।

Those who continuously chant the Mahā Mantrā named Shri Rām, they get rid of all diseases and definitely attain rare salvation.

म्लेक्षतुल्याः कुलीनास्ते ये न भक्ता रघूत्तमे ।

संकीर्णयोनयः पूता नामगृह्णन्ति ये सदा ।।

Those who do not worship Lord Shri Ram even after being born in a good clan, they are worse than Maha chandal Mlechha, those who take birth in a lowly birth, always chant the name of Shri Ram, they are the most pure.

नास्ति नास्ति महाभाग कलेर्युगसमं युगम्।

स्मरणात् कीर्त्तनाद्यत्र लभते परमं पदम् ॥

O Mahabhag! There is no era like Kaliyug where only by chanting the name of Shri Ram, the supreme position is attained.

15. Vatsyayana Samhita ( वात्स्यायन संहिता)

तुला पुरुष दानानि दत्त्वा यत्फलमश्नुते।

तस्मादसंख्यगुणितं रामनाम्नापि संलभेत्॥

The merit obtained by chanting the name of Sri Rama once is innumerable times greater than the merit obtained by donating a golden man etc.

स्त्रीराजबालहा चैव यश्च विश्वासघातकः ।

सर्वापहारी पापिष्ठो मार्गघ्नो ग्रामदाहकः ।।

मातृगामी सुरापश्च भूतधुक् सर्वनिन्दकः ।

मातृहा पितृहा चैव भ्रूणहा गुरुतल्पगः॥

ते चान्ये चैव पापिष्ठा महापापयुताश्च ये ।

सर्वपापैः प्रमुच्यन्ते रामनाम्नस्तु कीर्त्तनात् ॥

Killer of woman, king and child, traitor, looter of everything, great sinner, robber of travelers, setting fire to village, kāami for mother, drunkard, traitor, slanderer of all, the murderer of mother, father and womb, the one who goes with the teacher's wife and others who are very sinful and great sinners, all of them are freed from all sins by chanting the name of Shri Rām.

हेमभारसहस्रैश्च कुरुक्षेत्रे रविग्रहे।

गजाश्वरथदानैश्च देवालय प्रतिष्ठया ।।

सेवनैः सर्वतीर्थानां तपोभिर्विविधैश्च किम् ।

श्रीरामनाम्नि सततं नित्यं यस्यास्ति निश्चयम्।।

What is the benefit of donating thousands of manas of gold, elephants, horses and chariots during the solar eclipse in Kurukshetra, building a temple and establishing the gods in it, consuming all the holy places and performing many kinds of austerities? One who has complete faith in Sri Rām Naam does not need to do any other karma.

घोरे कलियुगे प्राप्ते सर्वदोषैकभाजने।

रामनामरता जीवास्ते कृतार्थाः सुजीविनः।।

Those who are engaged in chanting the name of Lord Shriram even after the coming of this fierce Kaliyuga as this is only home of all defects. In fact, they are the only ones whose life is successful.

रामनामपरा ये च घोरे कलियुगे द्विजाः ।

त एव कृतकृत्याश्च न कलिर्बाधते हि तान्।।

O brahmins, those who are engaged in singing, remembering and chanting Shri Ram's name in this fierce Kaliyuga, they are the ones who are blessed, Kaliyuga does not hurt them.

समस्तजगदाधारं सर्वेश्वरमखण्डितम् ।

रामनाम कलौ नित्यं ये जपन्ति समादरात् ॥

ते धन्याः पूजनीयाश्च तेषां नास्ति भयं क्वचित्।

सत्यं वदामि विप्रेन्द्र ! नान्यथा वचनं मम ।।

The support of the whole world, the Sarveshwar and the Akhand Shri Ram Naam, those who recite with respect in this Kaliyug, they are blessed and worshipable, they have no fear of anyone anywhere.

16. Mahasambhu Samhita (महाशम्भु संहिता)

Shiv ji's sentence;

यत्र कुत्राशुभे देशे भवेद्रामानुकीर्त्तनम् ।

सर्वं तीर्थादिकं विद्धि महाघौघं हरं हि तत्॥

Any unholy place where the name of Shri Ram is chanted, consider that place to be the best of all pilgrimages, that place is also the destroyer of great sins.

श्रीरामनामाखिल मन्त्रबीजं सञ्जीवनं चेत् हृदये प्रविष्टम्।

हालाहलं वा प्रलयानलं वा मृत्योर्मुखं वा विशतां कुतो भी॥

Sri Rama Naam is the seed of all mantras and is life-giving. Once this Rama Naam enters the heart by the grace of Sant Sadhguru. So there is no fear for that seeker of even entering the mouth of death halahal poison, doom.

Whereas Shri Janaki's sentence towards Shri Ram in same samhita,

प्रणवं केचिदाहुर्वै बीजं श्रेष्ठं तथा परे।

तत्तु ते नाम वर्णाभ्यां सिद्धिमाप्नोति मे मतम्।।

Some people call Om and some people call monosyllable seeds Gam, Ham etc. as the best, but both of them (Om Gam, Ham etc.) are proved by these two characters "R" and "M". This is my opinion.

रामेति नाममात्रस्य प्रभावमतिदुर्गमम्।

मृगयन्ति तु तद्वेदाः कुतो मन्त्रस्य ते प्रभो।।

O lord! The effect of the name of Shri Ram is very difficult to obtain, all the Vedas search for it but cannot cross it, then where is this power in any other? One who can cross it.

रामनाम प्रभावेण स्वयंभूः सृजते जगत्।

विभर्ति सकलं विष्णुः शिवः संहरते पुनः॥

With the influence of the name Shri Ram, swayambhu Brahma creates the world, Lord Vishnu maintains and Shankar destroys.

17. Patanjali Samhita (पतञ्जलि संहिता)

पृथ्वीं शस्यसम्पूर्णां दत्त्वा यत्फलमश्नुते।

रामनाम सकृज्जप्त्वा ततोऽनन्तगुणं फलम्॥

The fruit that is obtained by donating the entire earth full of green grains, that same fruit is obtained by chanting the name of Shri Ram once.

रामेति नाम परमं मन्त्राणां बीजमव्ययम् ।

ये कीर्त्तयन्ति सततं तेषां किञ्चिन्न दुर्लभम् ॥

Nothing is rare for those who constantly chant the name of Shri Ram, the imperishable seed of all mantras.

रामनाम परब्रह्म त्यक्त्वा वात्सल्यसागरम्।

अन्यथा शरणं नास्ति सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ॥

I say truly that there is no other protector except the name of the ocean of affection, the Supreme Brahman, Sri Ram.

नाम संकीर्त्तनादेव सम्पूर्णफलदायकम्।

अन्यत् फल्गु फलं सर्वं मोक्षावधिमसंशयम्॥

It is possible to get the full fruit only by chanting the name of Shri Ram, not by other means. Because all other means are going to give insignificant results, at the most they are going to give even salvation, that too is certainly small in comparison to the blissful juice.

कलौ युगे राघवनामतस्सदा परं पदं यात्यनायासतो ध्रुवम्।

सर्वैर्युगैः पूजितमुन्नतं युगं समस्तकल्याणनिकेतनं वरम्।।

Kaliyug is worshiped, advanced, the foundation of all welfare and the best age than all other ages, because in this Kaliyug, by always chanting, remembering and singing the name of Shri Ram, one definitely attains the supreme position without any effort.

माङ्गल्यं सर्वपापघ्नमायुष्यमखिलेष्टदम्।

भुक्ति मुक्तिप्रदं पुण्यं रामनाम्नस्तु कीर्त्तनम्॥

Sankirtan of Śrī Rām Naam is very auspicious, destroyer of all sins, bestower of longevity and complete desires, bestower of enjoyment and liberation and sankirtan of Śrī Rām Naam is meritorious.

येऽहर्निश जगद्धातू रामनाम्नस्तु कीर्त्तनम् ।

कुर्वन्ति तान् नरव्याघ्र न कलिर्बाधते क्वचित् ॥

Oh best of men! Those who chant the name of the Father of the universe Lord Shri Ram day and night, Kali does not hurt them anywhere.

Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam SitaRam

Hail to Priya Pritam Sarkar ❤️

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Comment: Could you make your answers shorter, they're too long to be able to read.

Comment: You guys have problem on everything. It's my space and I will write as much as Hinduism Stack exchange has approved. Please do you work.

Comment: I have formatted part of your answer. As it is too long, there are part which are needed to be formatted. Please follow as I have done and make proper formatting.

Comment: Do you have any sense?? Hinduism Stack exchange is providing me space to write my answer! Am I writing for you? Who has said you to read whole? Seriously this worst writing portal I have seen....And you are it's cause.

Comment: Shiv Ji, Can you please answer this question? I have had this doubt for quite some time now https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56383/what-to-chant-as-nama-japa-sita-rama-or-just-rama

Answer (score 1):

**न चत्वारोऽपि वै वेदाः समन्त्राः सप्तकोटयः ।
न यज्ञा अश्वमेधाद्यास्तीर्थानि चापि कोटयः।।

न मेरुतुल्यदानानि न योगाश्च तपांसि च।
रामेति नाममात्रस्य तुलां यान्ति महामने।।**

Not even four Vedas, together with seven crore mahamantras, not even crores of sacrifices, such as Ashwamedha and holy places, neither gifts equal to mount Meru, nor yogas nor austerities, O great soul, they are not even equal to the mere name of Rama

(Aadi Ramayan 4.14.35 & 36)

**सप्तकोटयः महामंत्र आश्रित विभ्रम कारकाः।
एक एवं परो मंत्रः राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।**

~ There are 7 crore mahamantras that can delude mind. There is only one mahamantra ie ram naam with 2 akshars that is supreme to all 7 crore mahamantras

Saraswat tantra

**इत्यादयो महामंत्र वर्तन्ते सप्त कोटयः ।
आत्मा तेषां च सर्वेषां रामनाम्ना प्रकाशते।।**

~ There are seven crores of great mantras. The soul of all of them shines in the name of Rama

(Maha Ramayana)

अहं च शंकरौ विष्णुस्तथा सर्वे दिवौकस।

राम नाम प्रभावेण संप्राप्ता सिद्धमुत्तमाम्।

Brahma, vishnu and shankar have always chanted shri ram naam by which we all got siddhis

Vishnu Puran

**चतुर्युगेषु श्री राम नाम महात्म्यं उज्जवलं।
सर्वोत्कृष्टं न संदेहो कलौ तत्रापि सर्वदा।।**

Shri Ram is evident in all 4 yugas but in Kali yug, shri Ram naam is the only way to salvation

Sharda ramayan

**जगत्प्रभु परमानंद कारणं सदसत्परम्।
रामनाम पर ईशानं सर्वोपास्य परेश्वरम्।**

Skand Puran nirvan khanda

Shiv says:-
Shri ram naam is bhagwan of all universes, reason for ultimate joy, is beyond the greatest and smallest, should be worshipped and parameshwar

There are much more to show, but these shlokas will give best of idea.