# Is Nama Japa of both Sita Rama and Rama equivalent when it comes to spiritual merits?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, japa, nama-japa

Nama Japa is considered easiest path to get God's grace in Kali Yuga as it enkindles dormant Bhakt in one,s heart. However different saints give different names for Nama Japa. RamaNama is recommended by many saints.

But I have heard some people claiming that we should chant SitaRama or RadhaKrishna as it is Yugala Nama. Some even say that Sri Rama or even Sri Sita Rama should be chanted instead of Rama Nama alone while others recommend just Rama Nama. This can also apply names of Narayana(Lakshmi Narayana) and Krishna(Radha Krishna). There are even some arguements that we should chant Rama instead of Ram. I am posting some examples below :

[केवल राम राम जपें या सीताराम जपें? कृष्ण जपें या राधेकृष्ण जपें?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMestjsOA-M)

[क्या जपे राम-राम की सीता-राम !! कौन सा है प्रभावशाली ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kQ5Qvn2plA)

[Ram naam ki mahima](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNC5zgi4o-w)

[सबसे श्रेष्ठ कौन से नाम का जप करना चाहिए, श्रवण कीजिए पूज्यपाद जगद्गुरुदेव भगवान के श्रीमुख से](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/lOgEjC1fen8)

[Why should one chant the Name ‘Sree Ram’ instead of ‘Ram’?](https://ariseohindu.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/why-should-one-chant-the-name-sree-ram-instead-of-ram/)

[Sri Rama Navami – Ram or Rama?](https://mahaperiyavaa.blog/2017/03/19/sri-rama-navami-ram-or-rama/)

So what should we chant? Do both Namas have same effects? Can we chant both together or alternatively?

Comment: Both are nama japa so what to chant depends on your personal choice or how you were instructed in this regard.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for your comment! Its good to see you are still active on this site. Its been a while since I was last active here regularly.                   
 Anyways,  can I chant both Sita Rama and Rama together(alternatively) like they are very same name? I have heard from some that we should hold on to one name and chant it . We shouldnt jump from one to another and so on. Is it true?

Comment: Yes I am active ... now we can't see the last seen stat that is why we can't be sure when the user was last active .. and yes you can chant both the namas if you wish .. no problem.

Comment: Sticking to one deity is always good but chanting Sita Rama and Rama is not really deviating from one deity to another .. so no issues.

Comment: @Rickross thats good. Actually the reason I am not active anymore is because the android app doesnt work anymore and I rarely use PC.

Comment: @So  I can use alternatively... Thanks. But if it is possible is there any mention about this in our holy texts or by some saints of Nama Japa like Sita Ram Omkarnath, Radha Baba, Dongreji Maharaj, Karpatri Maharaj etc?

Comment: This is a long comment not answer in itself.
From Mahaperiyava's eternal message- (Kamakoti.org)-Sri Rama naama smarana is the sure succour in life's tribulations. Anjaneya who practised the japa of this taaraka mantra to perfection, is the embodiment of brahmacharya and valour, which are the most needed to endow us with strength to successfully go through the voyage of life. If we are anchored in Sri Rama and His supreme devotee, Sri Anjaneya, our mind will not be sullied by kaama or other passions, but will be disciplined to attain the Reality pointed out by the Vedas. You can see below are

Comment: Oh ok ... you can post on meta though about the App not working .. some might help. I am not sure about whether there is mention about Sita Rama as nama japa in any texts or not .. I will search for the same and let you know. Although I personally think that it is valid

Comment: @Rickross actually the app has been discontinued by SE. It was already abandoned in 2017 but since last year it is completely unsuable.  Please do inform me if you find any reference about the japa . Rama Nama is praised throughout the scriptures. Its possible some text might give importance to Sita Rama. japa. I was researching about the same and came to know about Rama Rahasya Upanishad but seems like only one english translation is available online which doesnt give all mantras in Sanskrit.. Even I personally feel it is valid.

Comment: Ok I will certainly inform you @Rishx

Comment: @rickross thanks. btw is there any new app for SE?

Comment: Don't think APP will function any more .. pls go through this post -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026

Comment: see this (https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Nama_Mantras) under the heading of Rama. You will see one nama mantra as " Sri Sita Raamacandrabhyam Namah" .. so Sita Rama is a valid nama japa .. more such examples can be found on the same page too @RishX

Comment: thanks @rickross

Comment: This is opinion based? Thats why I try to avoid this site. Whats opinion based about Nama Japa and whether to chant  Rama Nama with Sita Nama. Majoritarianism at its best.

Comment: Instead of asking "What to chant as Nama Japa, Sita Rama or just Rama? " you can ask "Are Sita-Rama and Rama both valid Nama Japa mantras or not?" @RishX

Comment: @rickross Is it okay now ?

Comment: Yes and I have cast my reopen vote @RishX

Comment: @rickross thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**यज्ञ दान तपस्तीर्थ स्वाध्याय अध्यात्म बोधतः।
कोटि संख्यं रामनाम्नि पावित्र्यं वर्तते नृपः।।
ततः कोटागुणं पुण्यम् अस्या नाम सनातनम्।
इति मत्वा भजन्त्येनां मुनयो नारदादयः।।**

आदि रामायण ३.५१.४७क-४९ख

यज्ञ, दान, तपस्या, तीर्थ गमन, स्वाध्याय, अध्यात्म ज्ञान से जितना पुण्य प्राप्त होता है उसका कोटि गुणा फल राम नाम मात्र से ही प्राप्त होता है और कोटि बार राम नाम जपने से जितना पुण्य प्राप्त होता उतना सीता नाम सनातन नाम से ही मिल जाता है इसी कारणवश नारद आदि ऋषि मुनि सीता राम जाप करते हैं।

**Narad** says:- The amount of virtue that Is obtained from Yajna, charity, penance, pilgrimage, self-study, spiritual knowledge, its result is obtained a million times only by the name of Ram and the amount of virtue that is obtained by chanting the name of Ram a million times, the same amount of virtue is obtained from the eternal name of Sita. It is said that for this reason Narad etc. Rishi Muni chants Sita Ram nam

And almost same thing is mentioned in lomesh samhita but there are some differences

**यज्ञ दान तपस्तीर्थ स्वाध्याय आत्मबोधतः।
कोटि संख्यं राम नाम्नि पावित्र्यं वर्तते प्रिये।।
ततः कोटि गुण पुण्यं सीता नाम सनातनम्।
इति ज्ञात्वा भजन्तयेतान् मुनयो नारदादयः।।**

Lomesh samhita

**Sadashiv** says:- The amount of virtue that Is obtained from Yajna, charity, penance, pilgrimage, self-study, spiritual knowledge, its result is obtained a million times only by the name of Ram and the amount of virtue that is obtained by chanting the name of Ram a million times, the same amount of virtue is obtained from the eternal name of Sita. It is said that for this reason Narad etc. Rishi Muni chants Sita Ram nam

From these refrence, the only conclusion is

**1 Sita naam= crores of ram naam**